# Centering text in div on small displays with Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this bootstrap row of two equal parts `col-md-6` as such:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<h1><strong>ELECTRICAL SERVICES</strong></h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 text-right" style="color:#333;">
<h1>Call <a style="color:#333;" href="tel:XXX">(08) XXX</a></h1>
</div>
</div>
```

When the collapse occurs for sm displays I would like the text to center itself in that case and smaller.

Is there a class such as `text-center-md` or `text-center-md`? or how else can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the class `text-right` with the classes `text-center text-md-right`.

That will center the text by default and right align it on screens that are `md` or larger.

To make the font size responsive, you'd need to create a custom class. Here's an example:

```
.h1special {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .h1special {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }
}
```

Here's a working code snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
.h1special {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .h1special {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1><strong>ELECTRICAL SERVICES</strong></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center text-md-right" style="color:#333;">
            <h1 class="h1special">Call <a style="color:#333;" href="tel:XXX">(08) XXX</a></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good extra info, probably need to learn more about em and rem usage.